# Test-Path Returning false eventhough it exists

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

Powershell command showing false , even though that path exist in registry, what wrong i am doing?

```
PS D:\Folder> Test-Path -Path 'HKU:\S-9-9-21-57989841-616249376-1801674531-2451702'
False
```

[image]

Comment: `HKU:` is not a default drive. Try `Test-Path Registry::HKEY_USERS\...` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drive `HKU:` is not defined by default.

Either use:

```
Test-Path -Path 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-9-9-21-57989841-616249376-1801674531-2451702'
```

or define the drive first:

```
$null = New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS
Test-Path -Path 'HKU:\S-9-9-21-57989841-616249376-1801674531-2451702'
```

and when finished remove that drive with `Remove-PSDrive -Name HKU`